# Can't get QUERY_STRING from proxy to application

Tags: c, nginx, fastcgi

My fastcgi application is able to read every parameter from nginx when I POST form data to my server except QUERY_STRING. Looking at CONTENT_LENGTH gives the correct length of the string and my browser shows the data being sent so I can only think something's not set or I'm looking in the wrong place.

My location file:

```
location /testpage/test {
    include fastcgi_params;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

    fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/fcgi-sock.fcgi;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /www/test-app;
}
```

My test app:

```
#include "/usr/local/include/fcgiapp.h"

int main()
{
    FCGX_Request request;

    FCGX_Init();
    FCGX_InitRequest(&request, 0, 0);
    while (FCGX_Accept_r(&request) == 0)
    {
        FCGX_FPrintF(request.out, "Content-type: text/html\r\n\r\n <h1>Hello World!</h1>");

        char* q=FCGX_GetParam("REQUEST_METHOD",request.envp);
        if(q) FCGX_FPrintF(request.out, "%s", q);   
        else FCGX_FPrintF(request.out, "nope");

        q=FCGX_GetParam("QUERY_STRING",request.envp);
        if(q) FCGX_FPrintF(request.out, "%s", q);
        else FCGX_FPrintF(request.out, "nope");
}
```

I know I need to parse the string but I just want to get the string in the first place and, as I said, I can print out REQUEST_METHOD and several other params, just not QUERY_STRING.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a normal POST, the data is not in QUERY_STRING, but is instead passed to the CGI process via stdin.  Look at `FCGX_Request.in`.

You *could* have a QUERY_STING too if your URL has `?a=b` in it, but that's not normal for a POST.

Comment: I should have known that. I see garbage printed now, not the form data. I presume cause I haven't parsed it and, iirc, there isn't even a terminator? FCGX_FPrintF(request.out, "%s", request.in);

Comment: You have CONTENT_LENGTH -- I don't know if you get EOF, but there shouldn't be a terminator.  Request.in isn't a string -- it's a Stream.  You use it like you would use FILE*

Comment: Edited my comment. Does that look right? request is initialized with FCGX_InitRequest(&request)

Comment: Try FCGX_GetStr instead, passing in CONTENT_LENGTH and a buffer big enough to hold it and a \0

Comment: I haven't quite solved the problem but you corrected the basics I had forgotten plus some new things and I'm on my way. Thanks!